# Apache Spark - Map Reduce Debugging Tips

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, apache-kafka

I am trying to implement Kafka - Spark environment. I am trying to debug my MapReduce logic (implemented in Java). Spark submit step is making it complicated to debug with break points in my algorithms. Incoming live data patterns are complex. It will be very time consuming process to simulate the complex algorithms. Better development environment will help developers to validate their map reduce logic on live stream data.

Please suggest any tips and tricks. Is it possible to have IDE breakpoints, or remote debugging with Apache-Spark.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters if you are developing streaming or batch spark application. You can always use intellij idea for graphical debugging of your application.

Also look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkOG_aJ9KjQ. In the end if you want to debug reactivity of your application according to data patterns I suggest to use Spark's internal tools to see for example how DAG is being created or how it's being distributed.

One thing I myself am working on is to use spark debugging tools, and build a log according to my application execution graph with added information that I get from profilers (usual OS tools like iotop or iostat) to find for example where I am not utilizing resources enough.

In the end you need these information together to make a decision and ironically it itself can become a data intensive application.